1 inch Copper pipe to new Navien Tankless - no hot water on other side of house
I just installed a Navien tankless condensing unit. It sits next to the kitchen, which gets really hot water. But on the other side of the house, the water isn’t even lukewarm. I’m running a 1 inch pipe out of the Navien, which branches into three-quarter inch pipes. Have I oversized my pipes?
I’m not getting hot water on the other side of the house. It’s about 40 feet away.
Maybe the Navien needs to be adjusted for more output?

Are you getting water anywhere other than the kitchen faucet? Problem might be that the other delivery point you are trying to draw from has a low flow rate and the tankless WH isn't coming on. What is the delivery point--a shower, a lavatory faucet . . . ? Some low flow shower heads will not have enough flow rate of hot water to turn on the WH. If the shower is not drawing hot water, try turning on the bathroom lavatory hot faucet on 1/3 or 1/2 and see if this turns on the WH. Best solution would be to turn down the output temp on the WH so a shower calls for more flow rate of hot.

Turn the hot water on at "the other side of the house". Go feel pipe coming from the water heater leading there. If the pipe is hot, you may have a malfunctioning anti-scald valve somewhere over there feeding cold into the hot line. Try closing the shutoff valves on all but one device at a time and check for hot water on the remaining device. It will take about a gallon to flush out the cold water sitting in 40 feet of 3/4" pipe before you'd have any expectation of hot water arriving.
